# Python - Object Orientation. Child class not inheriting from Parent class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Disclaimer:  This is my first foray into OOP so my apologies if my explanation of the problem isn't very clear.  I'm trying my best, but the terminology is still new to me.

Hi.  I'm following a beginner Python tutorial on Object Oriented Programming.  The tutorial is all about Parent and Child classes, and how Child classes inherit attributes from the Parent.

In order to explain the principle, the tutor discusses how to use the relationship between a parent class and several different child classes to create different types of coin.  The Parent class is called 'Coin'.  the child class is called Pound (I'm from the UK so we're using British coins).

```
import random

class Coin:
    def __init__(self, rare = False, clean = True, heads = True, **kwargs):
    for key,value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self,key,value)


    self.is_rare = rare
    self.is_clean = clean
    self.heads = heads

    if self.is_rare:  # In the tutorial, rare coins are worth more than 
        self.value = self.original_value * 1.25
    else:
        self.value = self.original_value

    if self.is_clean:
        self.colour = self.clean_colour
    else:
        self.colour = self.rusty_colour

    def rust(self):
        self.colour = self.rusty_colour

    def clean(self):
        self.colour = self.clean_colour

    def __del__(self):
        print("Coin Spent!")

    def flip(self):
        heads_options = [True, False]
        choice = random.choice(heads_options)
        self.heads = choice

class Pound(Coin):
    def __init__(self):
        data = {
            "original_value": 1.00,
            "clean_colour": "gold",
            "rusty_colour": "greenish",
            "num_edges": 1,
            "diameter": 22.5,
            "thickness": 3.15,
            "mass": 9.5
            }
        super().__init__(**data)
```

When I run this code, I type the following into IDLE:

```
one_pound_coin = Pound()
one_pound_coin.colour
```

This gives 'gold'.  However, if I run the following:

```
one_pound_coin.rust()
```

I get an error message which reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#133>", line 1, in <module>
    one_pound_coin.rust()
AttributeError: 'Pound' object has no attribute 'rust'
```

The expected behaviour is quite different.  What *should* happen is that the modifier runs without error and then, when you type `one_pound_coin.colour` IDLE should return "greenish".

The peculiar thing is that I am using *the exact same code* that the tutor is using.  I've gone through it with a fine-toothed comb and checked literally every single character, every space, everything.  The code works for the tutor in the video but it doesn't work for me.  Anyone know why that might be?

Comment: Your indentation is almost certainly to blame. What you have posted here wouldn't even compile; but probably you have the other methods indented inside the `__init__` method.

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar!  I fixed the indentation and now it works perfectly, and I'm kicking myself for missing something so obvious.  Cheers.